# Data not Posting to server

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I am trying to have my application upload the input from a user to a database that my partner set up. We referenced [Post request to server using HttpUrlConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37997163/post-request-to-server-using-httpurlconnection)
and especially https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wFrfgMu1Dyc but we still cannot get the data to update to the server. The application runs fine other than that. WE get some errors on Paramsize and attaching agent failed. Not sure how to solve as I couldn't find hints anywhere. 
Here is the Java

```
package com.example.rachael.benchlocker;


import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;

public class AddPackage extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText tracking;
String TrackingNumber;
Button pack_btn;
Integer len;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_package);

    tracking = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tracking);
    pack_btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.pack_btn);
    pack_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TrackingNumber = tracking.getText().toString();
            len= TrackingNumber.length();
            new 
UpdatePack().execute("http://spinner.homelinux.net:51532/api/barcodes");
        }
    });
}

public class UpdatePack extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    public UpdatePack(){

    }
   @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
       super.onPreExecute();
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String...params) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder= new StringBuilder();
        try{
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection =(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
            httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(15000);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStream outputStream=httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream));
            bufferedWriter.write(TrackingNumber,0,len);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();

            httpURLConnection.connect();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) !=null){
                stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            ;
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
       super.onPostExecute(s);
       Log.w("Result",s);
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Package Added",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        toast.show();
    }
}
}
```

and the errors

```
06-05 09:43:11.495 3442-3471/com.example.rachael.benchlocker E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
06-05 09:43:13.954 3442-3442/com.example.rachael.benchlocker E/ActivityThread: Attaching agent failed: /data/data/com.example.rachael.benchlocker/libperfa_x86_64.so=/data/local/tmp/perfd/agent.config
```

Thanks!

Comment: `httpURLConnection.connect();`. That is a little bit late isnt it? You already posted your string.

Comment: `bufferedWriter.write(TrackingNumber,0,len);`. That is not the way to write the contents of a string. And if it indeed only contains a number then the posting is done wrong. `bufferedWriter.write(TrackingNumber.getBytes());` would be a better start. And the content should be more like "trackingnumber=12345".

Comment: You should first tell how the server expects the data.

Comment: `String TrackingNumber;`. Please adhere to java standards. Change to `String trackingNumber;` to make your code readable.

Comment: You have three catch blocks. You should in everyone add a line to your stringbuilder wich contains e.getMessage(). Otherwise you dont know about those exceptions. Toast string s in onPostExecute().